# UICollectionView for custom, grid-like view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I need a very specific collection view for an app I'm working on and wonder whether `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` will be up for the task. Here's the functionality that basically sums up what I'm trying to achieve:

- I need a grid layout that doesn't wrap/flow when symbols are added. Instead rows/columns are added automatically to hold any newly added symbols.
- The user should be able to drag'n'drop symbols on a grid and the symbol then drops 'magnetically' into position in the grid.
- rows and columns can be added or removed to/from the grid.
- When a symbol is dropped between two other symbols the grid should automatically insert a new column for it.
- The grid needs to be performant and fluid, so that it can be comfortably navigated (I dimly remember some custom `UICollectionView` solutions that acted like spreadsheet grid but clearly were overkill for what I need).

I'm not very familiar with programming custom `UICollectionViewLayouts` yet (getting into the matter now). So I'd like to ask if the `UICollectionView` fits the bill for the above requirements or whether it's better to do something completely custom? Any hints and tips would be greatly appreciated!